# Lxc giving error at the time of shutdown

Tags: debian, lxc

I had installed lxc on my debian wheezy. Now during shutdown it give error /var/lib/lxc/*/status : no such file or directory. it show this line for 50-60 times then got shutdown.
why am i getting this error? is lxc not correctly installed? everything is working fine every lxc command is just getting executed perfectly. so why this error?

Comment: Shutdown of the machine or shutdown of a container?

Comment: @enzotib shutdown of the machine